# Genymotion SDK location file

Tags: android, genymotion, android-sdk-tools

I've set in the Genymotion to use the SDK that's being used by Android Studio instead of default Genymotion default tools(Settings--> Adb --> "Use Custom Android SDK Tools"). I was wondering where Genymotion stores this location(preferably on a MAC. I need this information because I want my test scripts to check and make sure that the SDK used by Genymotion is the same as the one being used by the Android project before launching on Genymotion and running any unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

The path to the `tools` directory `Genymotion` uses is `/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/tools`. It is not the full `SDK` it is just `aapt`, `adb`, and `glewinfo`.